Trouble Accessing Elements Within Shadow DOM (amplify-authenticator) Using Selenium
I'm having trouble locating an element on the page as it's enclosed within the amplify-authenticator section. Below is the code I'm using. Could someone please assist me with this? Your help would be greatly appreciated!
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Set up Chrome WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://vprismqc.vidgyor.com/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Wait for the amplify-authenticator element to be present
amplifier = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'amplify-authenticator')))
print("1")

# Access the shadow root of amplify-authenticator
shadow_root1 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.host', amplifier)
print("2")

# Find the amplify-sign-in component within the shadow root
sign_in_component = shadow_root1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'amplify-sign-in')
print("3")

# Access the shadow root of the amplify-sign-in component
shadow_root2 = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot.host', sign_in_component)
print("4")

# Locate the email input field and enter the email
email_input = shadow_root2.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/section/div/div[1]/div/amplify-authenticator/amplify-sign-in//amplify-form-section/form/amplify-section/section/amplify-auth-fields/div/amplify-email-field/amplify-form-field/div/div[2]/slot-fb/amplify-input/input')
email_input.send_keys('demo@vidgyor.com')

# Locate the password input field and enter the password
password_input = shadow_root2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'amplify-input[name="password"] input')
password_input.send_keys('password')

# Locate and click the sign-in button
sign_in_button = shadow_root2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'amplify-button[type="submit"] button')
sign_in_button.click()

I attempted to interact with elements within a Shadow DOM on the webpage "https://vprismqc.vidgyor.com/" using Selenium. Specifically, I tried to access the amplify-authenticator and its nested elements, such as the email and password input fields, by navigating through the Shadow DOM layers.
I expected to successfully locate and interact with the amplify-sign-in component and its child elements, including entering credentials and clicking the sign-in button. However, I encountered issues locating the elements due to their encapsulation within the Shadow DOM, which may require a different approach or additional steps to properly access and interact with them.
